# Emptied Trash, but MacBook Harddrive Full? (Big Slur 11.6)

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, disk-space

I am new to the Mac world. I deleted some VM's from my MacBook Pro. Despite deleting 200GB worth of files on a 500GB drive, the MacBook is showing only 32GB open.

What am I missing?

The steps I took were:

1. Deleted Parallels VM's totaling over 200GB
2. Emptied the Trash
3. Unchecked automatic backup in Time Machine
4. Deleted all Time Machine Backups from MachHD/Volumnes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/ MacBook Pro
5. Restarted
6. Run Disk Utility\First Aid

Comment: Ouch!  The issue was when you tried to delete bits of Time Machine manually. That *never* works. On an external volume, the 'fix' is to switch off Time Machine & unlink the backup volume, reformat the volume entirely, then start over. I have no idea how you'll get out of it on the boot volume. Wish you luck.

Comment: I turned off my MacBook over the weekend, and now the data is cleared. Seriously what the heck.Time machine has been off since Friday. Now it's Monday. Perhaps a background cleanup?

Comment: It should automatically cycle round the local backups. I've no experience with what it will attempt to do if you throw them away manually.